# Inconsistent sound support from Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, usb, audio, windows-8.1, bluetooth

I hope I can explain my problem as complete as possible.

Recently I got me a pair of bluetooth headphones, because I loathe cables. I also got a bluetooth dongle for my windows desktop. I plugged it in, it connected to the headphones, so far its fine.

It detects 2 devices - a stereo headphone and a mono audio/microphone device. I put the stereo one on standard and it seemed to play fine - until I changed to another application. Then the sound stopped and I couldn't get it back on, not even by switching off the phones. I could restart that particular application (browser) and the sound would return for the USB speakers I am using.

And this is the problem - when I try using the headphones, the Windows 8.1 only randomly decides to decide to output the sound of one application through it - for as long as I don't change the window focus or even go to the start menu. And the sound won't come back even after I switched them off. Sometimes there is not total silence but random sound pieces of less than half a second, no consistency. When I try to plug the headphones in via USB, I get the same behaviour.

The problem can neither be the dongle (it works perfectly with mouse, keyboard and whatever else bluetooth I could find) or the headphones (they work perfectly with the mobile phone, tablet and got great reviews at the shop). I think the problem must be with Windows.

Is it possible to teach Windows 8.1 to play nice with more than one sound device? If not, the system is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly enough, i had a similar issue.
this is how i fixed it:
with the headphones/speakers unplugged,
right click on the speaker icon in the task bar, then select *recording devices*
enable all disabled devices, even if they say "currently unavailable". hit apply->ok

right click on the speaker icon in the task bar, then select *playback devices*
make sure you have the correct default device set, if not, set a device as default.

hope this helps.

Comment: They were all already enabled. But it seems to work now after I went to that menu and clicked "ok". I seriously have no idea why. I can switch them on and off and everything, it just works as expected. Weird.